# Trained ANN model does not predict correctly on testing data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a training and the testing data sets. I trained the ANN model by using keras and tensorflow. When testing data is used for predictions the model gives all outputs as one category. The code and confusion metrics results are with here along with the data set. Why model is not working in a proper way.

```
from keras.models import Sequential, model_from_json
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils
import numpy
import pandas as pd

# Import training dataset
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score

training_dataset = pd.read_csv('training_dataset.csv', header=0)
train_x = training_dataset.iloc[:, 0:21].values
train_y = training_dataset.iloc[:, 21].values

# Import testing dataset
test_dataset = pd.read_csv('test_dataset.csv', header=0)
test_x = test_dataset.iloc[:, 0:21].values
test_y = test_dataset.iloc[:, 21].values

# Encoding training dataset
encoding_train_y = np_utils.to_categorical(train_y)

# Encoding testing dataset
encoding_test_y = np_utils.to_categorical(test_y)

# Creating a model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=21, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))

# Compiling model
 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
['accuracy'])

# Training a model
model.fit(train_x, encoding_train_y, epochs=1000, batch_size=20)

# Evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(test_x, encoding_test_y)
print("Accuracy of the Model : %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))

#testing_data = pd.read_csv('testing_dataset.csv', header=0)
#testing_x = testing_data.iloc[:, 0:4].values
#training_y = testing_data.iloc[:, 4].values

predictions = model.predict_classes(test_x)
print(confusion_matrix(test_y,predictions))
print(accuracy_score(test_y, predictions)*100)
print("Predictions : ",predictions)
#rounded = [round(x[0]) for x in predictions]
#print("Predictions : ",rounded)

# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")

# later...

# load json and create model
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("model.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")
```

[Training and testing data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=142i1CSoDwzpOHPoHPAfdO7INAun2zzQW)

### Confusion matrix i got

```
> [[ 0  0  0 49  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 50  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 50  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 50  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 50  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 50  0  0]]
16.722408026755854
Predictions :  [3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3]
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: This model is used to find rice category. When using image of rice seed,features are extracted and write to csv file as training and testing data. I used 6 categories but after trained the model always it predict one category for all the test data. When the relevant features are extracted the specific category must be predicted.

Comment: Your network has ReLU at the output, where it should have a softmax instead.

Comment: I used softmax also. It increased little bit of accuracy of the model. But it also could not get expected predictions.